# Does the TV Tuner Terratec T1 work well?

Tags: 10.10, mythtv, tv-tuner

I'm planning to buy Terratec T1 TV tuner and i'd like to know if it works on ubuntu "out-of-the-box" meaning that there is no need to recompile kernel or doing advanced installatons. Has any1 tested it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it works out of the box, though I've not tested it.

It looks like you'll need to download the drivers from here http://linux.terratec.de/tv_en.html

From the readme.txt file within the above download, there are some caveats:

```
8.  Known problems & limitations

    a.CPU architecture:

        Currently only x86 architecture is supported.  

    b.USB support:

        Currently only USB2.0 is supported.

    c.Device VID/PID:

        0x048D/0x9005; 0x048D/0x9006.

    d.IR is supported and IRTable is named "af35irtbl.bin".

    e.Officially supported distributions:

        Linux Kernel - kernel 2.6.10 upward.
```